# iOs, curling pages, yet another question

Tags: ios, ios4

I am writing a book reader, and i very much want to have a cool page turning functionality.

I noticed, that in UIView there are two pre-built types of animations between two views: flipping around the vertical axis, and curling around the horizontal one, but no curling around the vertical axis. Is there possibly a way of tricking the curling transition into thinking that the vertical axis is in fact horizontal?

I *have* seen some open-source third-party libraries for turning pages, but they all seem pretty old and kind of slow or glitchy, so i'd rather use just simple sliding-in of a new view and sliding-out of the old view. But if there were a way to use Apple's libs for that, that'd be cool. It *is* strange they opened the vertical curling, and 'hid' the horizontal one.

Best regards, 
Timofey.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a way to use the vertical curling of apple's libs. Even if there is a way to do it, app store will reject the app since it is not the documented way of doing stuff.

This link will give more info:
http://oleb.net/blog/2010/06/app-store-safe-page-curl-animations/

Leaves(http://github.com/brow/leaves) is a very good open source library to give the vertical curl effect. I have tried the Leaves library to use in my project, it is very easy to understand how the animation effect is achieved by going thru the code. The problem is, it does not support to have dynamic controls like UIView on the page. But if you dont have any UIView and can draw a static page, Leaves is very good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still, that is not quite what i would like to have (i mean, the lib). Looking forward to their presentation of iOs 5, though ;)